# Does const_cast return the type specified inside angular bracket

Tags: c++, casting, constants

I am little confused with the return type of `const_cast`? Does the type inside the angular brackets `<>` is the return type?

```
const int i = 5;
int b = const_cast<int&>(i);
```

Is `const_cast` returning `int&` (integer reference), if yes then why how we storing it in integer? Or we should modify the code to:

```
const int i = 5; 
int & b  = const_cast<int&>(i);
```

Answer (score 3):

> Does const_cast return the type specified inside angular bracket

It evaluates to an expression of the type in the angular brackets. What matters here is how you use that expression:

```
const int i = 5;
int b = const_cast<int&>(i);
```

In this case, `b` is just a copy of `i`. The cast is not required.

```
const int i = 5; 
int & b  = const_cast<int&>(i);
```

Here, `b` refers to `i`. Note that using it to modify the value of `i` is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Did u mean this 
But this is working fine , I didnt get any undefined behavioru int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const int i=5;
    int &b = const_cast<int & >(i);
    b++;
    return 0;
}

Comment: @Maddyfire: Yes, you are getting UB, you just didn't notice it! That's the thing with UB.

Comment: @Maddyfire It is undefined behaviour. You can't expect the program to do produce any particular result. It could to whatever it wants.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. But instead of *returning* you should say that the type of the resulting expression *is* the type in `<>`.

When that type is a reference, as in `const_cast<int&>`, it means that it is a l-value. In the first case there is no difference, as it is immediately converted to an r-value anyway. But then, the `const` in such an r-value is ignored, so:

```
int b = const_cast<int&>(i); //ok
int b = const_cast<int>(i);  //also ok
int b = i;  //hey! also ok
```

In the second case there is a difference, because there is no l-value to r-value conversion:

```
int &b  = const_cast<int&>(i); //ok
int &b  = const_cast<int>(i); //error: cannot bind a reference to an r-value
int &b  = i; //error: cannot bind a `int&` to a `const int&`
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does the type inside the angular brackets <> is the return type?

Yes, the return type of `const_cast<int&>(i)` is `int&`. After that you assign it to a `int`, and the value get copied.

And in `int & b  = const_cast<int&>(i);`, you assign it to a `int&`, now `b` is the reference to `i`. Pay attention to that any modification on `b` will cause [undifined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).